# Struggling with my procedure in Java

Tags: java

I'm currently struggling to make my procedures to work. I'm having to do this all as objects This is what I have in my main file currently:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Room[] myHotel = new Room[6];
        //myHotel[x]  = new Room();
        myHotel[0]  = new Room();
        myHotel[1]  = new Room();
        myHotel[2]  = new Room();
        myHotel[3]  = new Room();
        myHotel[4]  = new Room();

        String roomName = null;
        String choice;
        int roomNum = 0;
        initialise(myHotel);

        while ( roomNum < 5 )
        {
         System.out.println("Hotel Booking Options");
         System.out.println("V: To View all rooms");
         System.out.println("A: To Add a customer to a room");

         choice = input.next();

         if (choice.equals("V")) //views all the rooms 
         {   
            view(myHotel, roomName);     
         }
         if (choice.equals("A")) //To add a customer to a room
         { 
            System.out.println("Enter room number (0-5) or 6 to stop:" ); 
            roomNum = input.nextInt(); 
            System.out.println("Enter name for room " + roomNum + " : " ) ; 
            roomName = input.next(); 
            myHotel[roomNum].mainName = roomName ;
            //myHotel[roomNum].setName(roomName);
            add(myHotel, roomName);
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
    private static void initialise( Room hotelRef[] ) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++ ) hotelRef[x].mainName = "empty";
    System.out.println( "initilise ");
    }
public static void view(Room myHotel[], Room roomName){
    for (int x = 0; x <5; x++)
    {
        int z = 0;
        Room Roomname = roomName;
        myHotel[z]= Roomname;

        if (myHotel[x].mainName.equals("empty"))
            System.out.println("room " + x + " is empty");
        else {
            System.out.println("room " + x + " occupied by " + myHotel[x].mainName);
            //System.out.println("room " + x + " is occupied by "+ myHotel[x]);
        }
    }
}
private static void add(Room myHotel[], String roomName){
    for (int x = 0; x <5; x++)
    {
        int z = 0;
        String Roomname = roomName;
        myHotel[z]= Roomname;
        if (myHotel[x].mainName.equals("empty"))
        {
            System.out.println("room " + x + " is empty");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("room " + x + " is occupied by "+ myHotel[x]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

In my other .java file with the object variables:

```
    public class Room {

    String mainName;
    //private String mainName;
    int guestsInRoom;
    public Room() {
    mainName = "k";
    System.out.println("made a room ");
    }
    public void setName(String aName) {
    System.out.println("add name class method ");
    mainName = aName;
    }
    public String getName() {
    return mainName;
    }
 }
```

I'm not sure how to fix line 54 - view(myHotel, roomName); Sorry if my variable names are confusing and misleading...

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: What is that function trying to do, what should it be doing, what are you seeing instead? SIMPLIFY!

Comment: There's a lot wrong with this program.  The problem you're having is that view() expects `(Room[],Room)`, but you're passing it `(Room[],String)`.

Comment: Some tips: The size of your array (Rooms) can be stored as a constant and used in all loops etc.Should there be 5 or 6 rooms? You could create your room objects in the initalize function. Variablenames should start with a small letter. In your view function you are passing a string instead of a Room object.